# how to check if a checkbox is checked and append its image to another div

Tags: jquery

I want to check if .addtocomparelist is checked (there are so many checkboxes with this class), take its value and find the element that has the same ID as the taken value, then find a certain image and a text inside it, and append it to another div, here is what I wrote, but it does not work!

```
if($('.addtocomparelist').prop('checked')) {
        var x = $(this).val();
        var img = $('#' + x).find('.productimage img');
        var name = $('#' + x).find('.productname').text();
        $('#comparelist').find('ul').append('<li>' + img + name +'</li>');
}
```

HTML Code:

```
        <div id="filterResult" class="grid">
        <ul>
            <li class="filteredproducts" id="p1">
                <div class="specialoffertag">
                    <img src="ui/css/img/filterResults/SpecialOffer.png" alt="پیشنهاد ویژه" />
                </div>
                <div class="compareResults">
                    <label class="addtocomparelist">مقایسه
                        <input type="checkbox" name="addtocomparelist" value="p1" class="addtocomparelist" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <a href="#" title="" class="productimage"><img src="ui/css/img/filterResults/Mobile-Samsung-Galaxy-Note-3-N9000-32GB1064d4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <div class="productcolors">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="redproduct">قرمز</li>
                        <li class="blackproduct">مشکی</li>
                        <li class="whiteproduct">سفید</li>
                    <div class="clearfloat"></div></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="productrate">
                    <span class="usersrate"><span>امتیاز کاربران ( از 1044 رای )</span> 7.0</span>
                    <span class="stars"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="seperation"></div>
                <a class="productname" href="#" title="">Samsung Galaxy Note III</a>
                <a class="productnamefa" href="#" title="">گوشی موبایل سامسونگ گلکسی اس5 - 16 گیگابایت</a>
                <div class="productdesc">
                    <p><span>مشخصات کلی:</span>یک سیم کارته - وزن : 130 گرم - مناسب برای عکاسی</p>
                    <p><span>پردازنده:</span>Exynos 5 Octa 5410 Chipset Quad-Core Cortex-A15 and Quad-Core Cortex-A7 CPU's</p>
                    <p><span>صفحه نمایش:</span>صفحه نمایش رنگی لمسی خازنی از نوع Super AMOLED - سایز صفحه نمایش : 4.99 اینچ - دارای رزولوشن 1920 × 1080 - تراکم پیکسلی : 441 پیکسل بر اینچ - قابلیت نمایش 16 میلیون رنگ</p>
                    <p><span>حافظه:</span>حافظه داخلی 16384 مگابایت - حافظه رم 2048 مگابایت - قابلیت نصب کارت حافظه از نوع Micro SD</p>
                    <p><span>شبکه های ارتباطی:</span>3G - GPRS - قابلیت اتصال به اینترنت از طریق وای فای - GPS - NFC - بلوتوث</p>
                    <p><span>دوربین:</span>13.0 مگاپیکسل - فوکوس اتوماتیک - فلاش - دوربین مکالمه ویدئویی</p>
                    <p><span>صدا:</span>فیش 3.5 میلیمتری هدفون</p>
                    <p><span>امکانات نرم افزاری:</span>سیستم عامل Android 4.2 Jelly Bean - پشتیبانی از جاوا - نمایش فایلهای مایکروسافت آفیس - نمایش فایلهای PDF</p>
                    <p><span>سایر مشخصات:</span>قطب نما - باتری 2600 میلی آمپر ساعتی</p>
                </div>
                <span class="productprice">1,800,000<small>تومان</small></span>
                <a href="#" title=""><img class="addtocart" src="ui/css/img/filterResults/addtocart-min.png" alt="اضافه به سبد خرید" /></a>
                <a href="#" title=""><img class="moredetails" src="ui/css/img/filterResults/productdetail.gif" alt="جزئیات محصول" /></a>
            </li>
            <li class="filteredproducts" id="p2">
                <div class="specialoffertag">
                    <img src="ui/css/img/filterResults/SpecialOffer.png" alt="پیشنهاد ویژه" />
                </div>
                <div class="compareResults">
                    <label class="addtocomparelist">مقایسه
                        <input type="checkbox" name="addtocomparelist" value="p2" class="addtocomparelist" />
                    </label>
                </div>
                <a href="#" title="" class="productimage"><img src="ui/css/img/filterResults/Mobile-Samsung-Galaxy-Note-3-N9000-32GB1064d4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <div class="productcolors">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="redproduct">قرمز</li>
                        <li class="blackproduct">مشکی</li>
                        <li class="whiteproduct">سفید</li>
                    <div class="clearfloat"></div></ul>
                </div>
                <div class="productrate">
                    <span class="usersrate"><span>امتیاز کاربران ( از 1044 رای )</span> 7.0</span>
                    <span class="stars"><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-full"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
                </div>
                <div class="seperation"></div>
                <a class="productname" href="#" title="">Samsung Galaxy Note III</a>
                <a class="productnamefa" href="#" title="">گوشی موبایل سامسونگ گلکسی اس5 - 16 گیگابایت</a>
                <div class="productdesc">
                    <p><span>مشخصات کلی:</span>یک سیم کارته - وزن : 130 گرم - مناسب برای عکاسی</p>
                    <p><span>پردازنده:</span>Exynos 5 Octa 5410 Chipset Quad-Core Cortex-A15 and Quad-Core Cortex-A7 CPU's</p>
                    <p><span>صفحه نمایش:</span>صفحه نمایش رنگی لمسی خازنی از نوع Super AMOLED - سایز صفحه نمایش : 4.99 اینچ - دارای رزولوشن 1920 × 1080 - تراکم پیکسلی : 441 پیکسل بر اینچ - قابلیت نمایش 16 میلیون رنگ</p>
                    <p><span>حافظه:</span>حافظه داخلی 16384 مگابایت - حافظه رم 2048 مگابایت - قابلیت نصب کارت حافظه از نوع Micro SD</p>
                    <p><span>شبکه های ارتباطی:</span>3G - GPRS - قابلیت اتصال به اینترنت از طریق وای فای - GPS - NFC - بلوتوث</p>
                    <p><span>دوربین:</span>13.0 مگاپیکسل - فوکوس اتوماتیک - فلاش - دوربین مکالمه ویدئویی</p>
                    <p><span>صدا:</span>فیش 3.5 میلیمتری هدفون</p>
                    <p><span>امکانات نرم افزاری:</span>سیستم عامل Android 4.2 Jelly Bean - پشتیبانی از جاوا - نمایش فایلهای مایکروسافت آفیس - نمایش فایلهای PDF</p>
                    <p><span>سایر مشخصات:</span>قطب نما - باتری 2600 میلی آمپر ساعتی</p>
                </div>
                <span class="productprice">1,800,000<small>تومان</small></span>
                <a href="#" title=""><img class="addtocart" src="ui/css/img/filterResults/addtocart-min.png" alt="اضافه به سبد خرید" /></a>
                <a href="#" title=""><img class="moredetails" src="ui/css/img/filterResults/productdetail.gif" alt="جزئیات محصول" /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: show us the html code...

Comment: Please share some piece of HTML here

Comment: Have you put it in some change event of checkbox.

Comment: can't find `comparelist` in the html.

Comment: @Jai it's an empty div somewhere else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/qEZ6y/2/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        var id = $(this).val();
        var text = $('#' + id).text();
        var imgSrc = $('#' + id + ' img').attr('src');
        alert(text + ' ' + imgSrc);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: now I need to know how to take the checkbox's value, find the element with the same ID, find the image and text inside it, and append them to another list.

Comment: I updated the fiddle. See if something like that works for you.